# How can I do face recognition of two images using opencv java in android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to create a face recognition application in android studio in java language. I spent considerable amount of time, searching for step by step guides for achieving this function. I found many tutorials for python language and i couldn't find any proper tutorial or atleast a video tutorial for java.

Can someone please provide me with a proper link with the steps to do face recognition with OpenCv in android using java language.
I'm new to OpenCv, so i have no big idea on its functions.

Your help is highly appreciated

**Update 1 ::**
I'm trying to capture the image of the user and then cross check the taken image with an image that is already available in the gallery.
I want to know if both are the same so that i can allow the user to use the application.

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a Java program that utilised OpenCV for facial recognition earlier this year.
For me it was an utter nightmare. Guides to doing this on Java are basically nonexistent and the documentation for Java OpenCV is very poor.

What I ended up doing to get to grips with OpenCV was I used [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/) to learn how OpenCV works and then just trawled through the [OpenCV javadocs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/index.html) until I found the most similar classes to what was being used in PyImageSearch.

There are a few guides for OpenCV recognition using Java (I'll have a look through my notes when I get a chance and see if I saved any links for my own reference) but none of them were for what I needed.

If you edit your post with some more information on the recognition you're trying to do (video or jpeg or png?; frontal faces or side faces?; specific faces or faces in general?) I may be able to help a little more.

The Youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLDk0xqo2QeH-4XZ93KH38jOoGOd60-2GO&v=YkC55xDREKE) that @Varma posted might help you get to grips with OpenCV as a whole, but that series doesn't seem to cover facial recognition.

## EDIT #1

Okay, recognising who someone is via an image is definitely doable with OpenCV, but it's not something I've done. Here's [a PyImageSearch page](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/) on how to do it in Python. The methodology for doing it in Java with OpenCV will most likely be more or less the same even thought the syntax will - of course - make it look very different (should mostly be a matter of finding the equivalent Java classes and methods).

If it proves difficult, there are alternatives to OpenCV you could use, like [these](https://applikeysolutions.com/blog/how-to-make-a-mobile-app-for-face-recognition) or [Google's API](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/face-detection/index.html?index=../../index#3). Keep in mind though that facial recognition is [not very secure](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/01/08/facial-recognition-on-42-android-phones-beaten-by-photo-test/) and does come with some [controversy](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/09/technology/facial-recognition-race-artificial-intelligence.html).